# Bringing limit inside a function when computing the limit of sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose we have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \geq 0}$ and we want to find the pointwise limit of the sequence, i.e., we want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, can we bring the limit inside the function? I understand why it works when we have a continuous function $g(x)$, i.e., we can write $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = g(\lim_{x \to a} x)$, but what about taking limit over $\mathbb{N}$?

For example if we have the sequence of functions defined by $f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + x^2}$ and we want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + x^2}$ is this equal to $\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n} + x^2)}$ and if so is it because the square root function is continuous?
I guess that this is true because clearly the limit of the sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ is $|x|$, but I am having trouble proving it without contingence on the above.

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt x$ is continuous and you can take the limit inside. Why do you doubt that?

Answer (score 1):

When finding the pointwise limit you are essentially finding a a limit for the sequence $\{ f_n(x) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ after fixing $x$. After fixing an $x$, $x$ is essentially a constant, and you need to consider the dependence on $n$.

If $f_n(x)=g \big( h_n(x) \big)$, where  $h_n(x)\overset{n\to \infty}{\to}h(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is continuous at $h(x)$, then $f_n(x)\overset{n\to \infty}{\to} g\big( h(x)\big)=g\big( \lim_{n\to \infty} h_n(x) \big)$.

In your case, $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}+x^2$.

Comment: Ok thank you, so essentially this follows from the sequential definition of continuity?

Comment: If you mean $x_n\to x_0$ implies $g(x_n)\to g(x_0)$ for any $x_n\to x_0$, then yes.